# Can commit files via Tortoisesvn (TortoiseProc.exe) but not svn commit (svn.exe)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, teamcity

So I am trying to commit a folder to the repository that has changes to it. I am able to right click that folder and commit (via tortoise svn) without any problems, it works fine. However when I try and commit through a .bat file using svn.exe (as opposed to TortoiseProc.exe), none of the changes are committed to the repository. There are no error messages, and nothing shows up in the log. The reason I want to run it in a batch file is so I can automate the process through TeamCity. The problem with using tortoise svn is that the commit dialog procs and you have to manually hit "ok". So I am looking for a solution where this commit dialog pop up is bypassed (if that can even be an option) OR a way to commit the folder via the batch script. I have seen this similar if
not same question posted but none of the answers seemed to help out or relate to this issue (which could be due to my lack of understanding so 
I am open for any kinds of explanations). This is the script that I am running:

```
@echo off
echo.
echo. [ SVN Committer ]
set SOURCE=WebServiceDLLs\
set SVN=C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin
echo.
echo. Committing %SOURCE% to SVN...
"%SVN%\svn.exe" commit %SOURCE% -m "Committing Web Services, CCD, CCR, QA,    ePrescription" > deploy2.log
echo. done.
echo.
echo. Operation complete.
```

I have tried using the full path for the SOURCE variable and it still does not work. Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried changing the values of `-m` or leaving out the trailing backslash in `SOURCE` ? Did you do a `echo %errorlevel%` after calling svn ? What happens if you provide a full path including drive letter for `SOURCE` ?

Comment: @Marged, thank you for your response. I have tried changing the values of -m to empty quotes and just "commit" which didn't work. I also tried removing the trailing backslash in source which also didn't seem to work (both with the full path and just WebServiceDLLs). Echo %errorlevel% outputs a 0, and using the full path including the drive gives the same result as just giving WebServiceDLLs as the path.

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to comment and help, but I think I found my answer here: [link](http://www.wandisco.com/svnforum/forum/opensource-subversion-forums/scripts-contributions/8171-automatically-commit). Exactly what I needed.

Comment: That's good news. You can answer your own question and please do so.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again for taking the time to comment and help, but I think I found my answer here: [link](http://www.wandisco.com/svnforum/forum/opensource-subversion-forums/scripts-contributions/8171-automatically-commit). Exactly what I needed.

I think the issue for me was that I was not checking for added or deleted files, which were the changes I was trying to commit. Since what I implemented in my above question does not check for that, it was not committing anything. This is what I ended up using to solve which was taken from the mentioned link:

```
cd "Path\to\project"
FOR /f "tokens=1,* delims=!" %%a in ('svn status ^| find "!"') do (
  for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%x in ("%%a") do svn del "%%x"
)
FOR /f "tokens=1,* delims=?" %%a in ('svn status ^| find "?"') do (
  for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%x in ("%%a") do svn add "%%x"
)
svn commit -m "System Automated Commit"
```